# Python Selenium Choose date from a Datepicker Calendar

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I want to select a date (dd/mm/yyyy) from a Datepicker calendar

[image]

So I used the following code, which doesn't display an error but doesn't work on the browser (I don't have the date selected that I'm looking for).

```
dateDebut=driver.find_element(By.XPATH ,'XPATH on Browser') #here I copied the XPATH on browser
dateDebut.send_keys('01/01/2021')#I have no error, but the date on the browser is not "01/01/2021"
```

Any thoughts which can point me in the right direction would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the URL if it is public?

Comment: @Shawn, sorry I can't share the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dateDebut.get_property('value')
dateDebut.clear() 
dateDebut.send_keys("01/01/2021")
```

Comment: This answer could be improved with an explanation. Not sure calling `get_property` is nessesary.